# Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response. (node, react, axios)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

This is in my server.js:

```
app.use(helmet())
app.options('*', cors())
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Cache-Control')
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.sendStatus(200)
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

I have a basic node/webpack/react situation.  I am making my request in the client with axios.  I know that the request is solid, because I have tested it in isolation.  I have also tried every combination of `Access-Control-Allow-xxxxx` that I have found/can think of. It has to be something with this middleware.  Any help/insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you add `Authorization` to your `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`?

Comment: Instead of `res.setHeader` try `res.header`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to make a api call from your client to the express/node server, yes? Have you tried using a proxy?

try setting the port of your server to something like localhost:5000. Then try

```
app.use(cors())
```

instead of

```
app.options('*', cors())
```

then back in your client side in your React package.json simply add a proxy

```
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

or whatever port your server is on.

That should solve your issue.